# Just moved my ubuntu server that I use as a Plex Media server to a different room in my house. Now I can't find my server on the network

Tags: server, ssh, ethernet, hdmi

Just moved my ubuntu server that I use as a Plex Media server to a different room in my house. Now I can't find my server on the network, and I can't ssh into it either.

I figured maybe it's ip address had changed and plugged an hdmi monitor into the physical server machine and it shows no signal.

This is a server that connects with ethernet only. It has no wi-fi adapter.

At first, I tried plugging in 3 different cat 8 cables into it and each time it showed on the router that it was connected but the orange light next to the ethernet input of the server did not glow orange as it has when it's been connected.

I tried restarting each time and only on the last cable did the connection glow orange when I plugged it into the machine

The server is running...I just can't see what is going on with it and can't find it on my network. Obviously Plex cannot connect to it. There were no warning beeps on the motherboard on any start up...

I SSH in from a Windows 11 laptop.

Also, I have a vpn installed on my Linksys router, but there is no instance of the server being active whether on VPN or off VPN.

Comment: Understood. Sorry I'll edit and add that.

Comment: As for release. I'm not sure since I can't get into the server to look. I nstalled it about 9 months ago with the most recent release and actually sudo apt update it yesterday.